# Как заменить атрибут Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В чем суть вопроса:
На сайте есть 5 карточек товаров, в каждой из которой есть кнопка "заказать". После нажатия кнопки появляется модальное окно с формой заказа, оно на сайте всего одно. Я прописал для каждой кнопки атрибут name с уникальным значением и хочу,чтобы при клике на кнопку:
1)Получать значение атрибута name и записывать его в переменную.
2)Менять значение атрибута в модальном окне с формой.
Первую часть кода я написал, т.е получил значение атрибута и записал в переменную, а как теперь значение переменной поместить в атрибут в форме с модальным окном не знаю.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button name="ns" class="tov-button">Заказать товар</button>
<div class="modal">
<form name="empty" class="modal-form"></form>
</div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tov-button').on('click', function () {
    let a = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.modal-form')
  });
});
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вы себе дальнейшую логику обработки этой формы на стороне сервера представляете? что вы хотите получить от формы? Если поле с именем товара, то и добавьте в форму `<input type="hidden" name="tovar" value="..." id="tovar"/>` и вписывайте туда то что извлекли с кнопки `$("#tovar").val(a)`

Comment: Да, в том-то и дело, что не представляю. Спасибо за помощь.